# windows SHARE_INFO_2 structure

Tags: windows, winapi

In the link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb525410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx the shi2_password field says

shi2_passwd

Pointer to a Unicode string that specifies the share's password when the server is running with share-level security. If the server is running with user-level security, this member is ignored. The shi2_passwd member can be no longer than SHPWLEN+1 bytes (including a terminating null character). Calls to the NetShareSetInfo function ignore this member. ***Note that Windows does not support share-level security.**

The documentation is about windows os, What does the Note means.

Answer (score 2):

From [Microsoft SMB Protocol Authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Share-level authentication indicates that access to a share is controlled by a password assigned to that share only. Unlike user-level security, this security level does not require a user name for authentication and no user identity is established.

From [Google Books: Integrating Linux and Windows](http://books.google.com/books?id=0SM3PEH9gagC&pg=PA222):

> [Share-level authentication] was the first security model that SMB had and is the only security model available in the Core and CorePlus protocols. Windows for Workgroups' vserver.exe implements share level security by default, as does Windows 95.

So your question:

> The documentation is about the Windows OS, what does the note mean?

I guess the struct member is there for backwards compatibility (so you can issue commands on servers that does support share-level authentication, and older client can still access newer servers) but not actively supported anymore.

Edit: as for the **support** part which you seem to be curious about: Windows features that are "not supported" are there and that for a variety of reasons:

- They can exist to help internal functions (no documentation, no support, you can maybe see or find the functionality but aren't supposed to use it).
- They can be marked deprecated or obsolete (documentation may exist, still no support, because the use of a different, newer implementation is recommended).

"Not supported" means you [can't issue a support call to Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/select/default.aspx?target=assistance) for help on the supbject, because they **do not support it (anymore)**. See for example [Support is ending for Windows XP - Microsoft Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/end-support-help) (an entire product where support is discontinued) or [CRT functions not supported with /ZW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/jj606124.aspx), where specific library functions are not supported in certain usage scenarios.

So while a "not supported" functionality may work entirely like you envisioned it, as soon as it doesn't, you're on your own.

As for your SMB question, which is answered by my two citations: share-level authentication was the first security implementation of SMB, but you're now not supposed to use anymore but user-level authentication instead.

Comment: This explains nothing. The note says **Note that Windows does not support share-level security**. What does  it mean. Which version of windows is not considered as windows.

Comment: @Talespin it explains everything. See edit to my answer where I explained what "support" means.